# Robot not visible in RViz (Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04, VMWare Fusion 10.0.1)

Tags: ros, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Going through a PacktPub book's tutorial on ROS, [Effective Robotics Programming with ROS](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Effective-Robotics-Programming-with-ROS). I'm hoping the community has solutions.

In Chapter 4, I tried running

```
roslaunch robot1_description display.launch model:="'rospack find robot1_description'/urdf/robot1.urdf"
```

and managed to get the rviz window up and running, However, there were no robots as described in the `.urdf` file in the `display.launch` file.

I have edited the last line as suggested in #q113561, but to no avail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274193/robot-not-visible-in-rviz-(kinetic,-ubuntu-16.04,-vmware-fusion-10.0.1)/) by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
Can you please tell us which OS this is, which version, how you installed it, how you installed ROS, and which version of ROS this is?

I've seen similar questions about RViz on certain Ubuntu versions not rendering correctly.

And for the future: please include that sort of information.

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-10-27**:
I am on VMWare Fusion 10.0.1, Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic.

Installed ROS on the ROS Kinetic Installation page.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-27**:
Btw: can you add a screenshot showing the RViz window, and add the console output you get after running the `roslaunch robot1_description ..` command?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-27**:
I've changed the title to better reflect the problem, and I've updated the formatting of your question a bit.

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-10-27**:
Console output:

PARAMETERS

- /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
- /rosdistro: kinetic
- /rosversion: 1.12.7
- /use_gui: False

Continued after due to comment length limit

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-10-27**:
NODES
/

joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)

robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)

rviz (rviz/rviz)

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-10-27**:
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found

process[joint_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [53550]

process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [53551]

process[rviz-3]: started with pid [53552]

How do I add a screenshot?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-28**:
Please *edit your question*, do not use comments. They are too limited and are not meant for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> roslaunch robot1_description display.launch model:="'rospack find robot1_description'/urdf/robot1.urdf"
> ```

Is this an actual copy-paste?

I ask because the `rospack find robot1_description` bit should be between *backticks* (`), not single quotes.

`rospack find ..` is a command that `bash` needs to execute before it lets `roslaunch` do its thing.

If you don't use backticks, but single quotes, your shell will not execute it and `roslaunch` is given the following string for the `model` argument:

```
'rospack find robot1_description'/urdf/robot1.urdf
```

which is obviously not correct.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-10-27**:
Yea, I found it odd!
It is a direct copy and paste but it might have been an error by the author (not the first). However, I did just `cd` into the path and did  `roslaunch robot1_description display.launch model:=./robot1.urdf`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-28**:
Try to use absolute paths. Relative paths will not work the way you expect them to. If:

```
roslaunch robot1_description display.launch model:="`rospack find robot1_description`/urdf/robot1.urdf"
```

works then I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with your setup.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
Did you get this to work?

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-11-06**:
Yes, I believe it is the VMWare issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:
Are you sure? The backticks vs single quotes did not influence the outcome at all?